# How does one reference a property list in a detail controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm building a drill-down application with a tab bar acting as the rootViewController. The app is fully functioning except for the detail view. I outlined three properties in my .plist: Title, Associated Image, and Industry Info.

So I created these variables in my header file:

```
@interface DetailView : UIViewController {

NSDictionary *industryData;

IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
IBOutlet UIImageView *associatedImage;
IBOutlet UITextView *industryInfo;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *industryData;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *associatedImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *industryInfo;

@end
```

I'm sure that I was able to get the second part of the viewDidLoad method right, but I'm having trouble getting it to associate with my .plist. I'm still confused on the first part, though:

```
{
NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *DataPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IndustryData.plist"];

NSDictionary *tempDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DataPath];
self.industryData = tempDict;
[tempDict release];

associatedImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[industryData valueForKey:@"Associated Image"]];
titleLabel.text = [industryData valueForKey:@"Title"];
industryInfo.text = [industryData valueForKey:@"Industry Info"];

[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I guess my question is rooted in the first five lines of code. I tried to apply what I did to the navigation part to the detail view, but when it loads there is no content on the screen. How do I get my details to associate with my original .plist?

Edit:

I figured this was worth adding, from my "IndustryView", aka the navigation's view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//Get the dictionary of the selected data source.
NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Get the children of the present item.
NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];

Dg3_z_Z4_8AppDelegate *AppDelegate = (Dg3_z_Z4_8AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if([Children count] == 0) {

    DetailView *dvController = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    [AppDelegate.indNavControl pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];

    [dvController release];
}
```

There is an else part, but it isn't particularly relevant here. Thanks!

Comment: Can you NSLog the contents of industryData, this would narrow down where the problem might be? Also, not sure what you are expecting to happen but it seems that all of your detail views would show the same data since it reads a hard coded plist.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle pathForResource:@"IndustryData" ofType:@"plist"]
```

Or, have the detail items as properties of your detail view controller, and set them before pushing.